# Array not being populated with directory contents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays

I'm trying to load the contents of a folder I have on my app directory called "shapes", I want to dynamically build buttons for each shape inside that folder. However, it can't find the contents of the directory, only when I specify to look in root it seems to work.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"shapes"];
NSLog(@"The array contains %d elements", [array count]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't have a folder, but a group in Xcode. When you drag a folder into Xcode to add it to the project, make sure to check "add folder references for added folders".

Comment: And I forgot the referencing part... sigh

Answer (score 2):

try below code:

```
NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [directories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *FilePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:Path];
// Enumerate directory
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSArray * items = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:DirPath error:&error];
```

it is used to fetch the patch of the forders and list of items in folder

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing the path as

> [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
>   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"shapes"];

and then try to get the contents from the path using NSFileManager.

Comment: Add "shapes" folder the way jtbandes describes and then follow my code to access it.